# ActionScript3 - how to handle NetConnection.Connection.Failed

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, netconnection

I have a video streaming app, and it uses Flash AS3.  It keeps getting a NetStatusEvent of "NetConnection.Connection.Failed", when i try to use it in my Windows Testing environment.  I need to make it work in my testing environments before i can launch this product.  How do i diagnose this problem?  What are common causes of this problem?

Thanks In Advance,
Ari Amiri

Comment: Are you making use of RTMP or RTMFP ?

Comment: Are you correctly setting the NetStream client object, and added the onMetaData, onPlayFinish... methods to it?

Comment: Yes but they don't pont towards anything

Answer (score 0):

Please given below check just verify:

1. Check URI with proper accesible IP Address
2. Check Firewall issue
3. check the Port 1935 is open or blocked in your server for RTMP
4. Check Server Streaming Server (RTMP Supporting Server Setup)

Comment: How did you produce there checklist? Is there some sort of documentation?

Comment: There is no such document where we can get all thing together. But We can find out all thing different on google or in different books.

Comment: I think some references would be nice since this is a some what useful list.